# How do I install rvm without root access?

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I would like to install the `travis` gem on a machine without ruby gems, and on which I don't have root.  (I want to encrypt something for use with travis.)  I decided to try to install rvm, because https://rvm.io/rvm/install suggests that it is an easy way to install ruby without root.  However, I ran into problems right away:

```
jgross@cagnode17:~$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13961  100 13961    0     0  15390      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  170k
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1083k  100 1083k    0     0   200k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--  199k

Installing RVM to /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.bashrc /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.bash_profile /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.zprofile.
Installation of RVM in /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# Jason Gross,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne

# In case of problems:
#      run and read: rvm notes
#         read docs: http://rvm.io/
#        talk to us: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (http://freenode.net/faq.shtml#plusr)
#   read cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
#  watch screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm
# open a bug report: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

rvm 1.22.2 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Checking requirements for debian.
Installing requirements for debian.
jgross password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': 
Sorry, try again.
jgross password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': 
Sorry, try again.
jgross password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': 
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

So I tried again:

```
jgross@cagnode17:~$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13961  100 13961    0     0  27936      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 27936
Please read and follow further instructions.
Press ENTER to continue.
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1083k  100 1083k    0     0   158k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--  186k

Upgrading the RVM installation in /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.bashrc /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.bash_profile /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.zprofile.
Upgrade of RVM in /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.rvm/ is complete.

# Jason Gross,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne

# In case of problems:
#      run and read: rvm notes
#         read docs: http://rvm.io/
#        talk to us: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (http://freenode.net/faq.shtml#plusr)
#   read cheatsheet: http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rvm
#  watch screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm
# open a bug report: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.


rvm 1.22.2 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Checking requirements for debian.
Installing requirements for debian.
jgross password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': 
Sorry, try again.
jgross password required for 'apt-get --quiet --yes update': 
sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.
Creating alias default for ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Recording alias default for ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Creating default links/files
ruby-2.0.0-p247 is not installed.
Could not load ruby ruby-2.0.0-p247.
/afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.rvm/scripts/alias: line 108: /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby: No such file or directory

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /afs/csail.mit.edu/u/j/jgross/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.
```

Trying `rvm install 1.8` gives me the same error message about debian requirements.  Do I have any option other than giving up rvm and building ruby from source?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### TL;DR

You're missing package dependencies needed to build Ruby.

### Packages and Autolibs

The issue your facing is that recent(ish) versions of RVM use a feature called [autolibs](https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs) that attempt to install package dependencies. Of course, you need *sudo* access to install system packages. You could try installing a Ruby interpreter with:

- `--autolibs=read-only` - to avoid the *sudo* error, but this is unlikely to result in a working binary.
- `--autolibs=rvm_pkg` - will use the old `rvm pkg install ...` to install missing dependencies if they can be provided by RVM, this will take long time and is not guaranteed to work.
- `--autolibs=read-fail` - to avoid the *sudo* error, it will produce list of dependencies to install for the next section.

### Ask Root to Install Package Dependencies

In general, the easiest solution is to ask root to [install the packages](http://rvm.io/rvm/prerequisites) that RVM expects. This should really be your first stop before doing anything else. There may be legitimate reasons to use static binaries or hand-build all your dependencies, but why not do things the easy way if you can?

### Try Pre-Built, Static Binaries

If you can't get the necessary packages installed, you can try the `rvm list remote` command to see if there are any pre-built binaries for your system that can be installed by RVM. If you're missing packages, then you might want to look for a static binary that you can use with the `rvm mount` command. You might even build the interpreter on another system, and mount it using the appropriate remote URL; see `rvm help mount` for details.